# MouseMove issue on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mousemove

I'm attempting to get a square shape to follow my mouse around on the canvas using "mousemove".

```
function start(){
    var canvastmp = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
    var canvas = canvastmp.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', trevor, false);
}
function trevor(pos){
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    var x = pos.clientX;
    var y = pos.clientY;
    canvas.fillRect(x-25,y-25,100,100);
}
window.addEventListener('load',start,false);
```

When I run it, nothing at all shows up. I've been tweaking it and scouring it for a while now, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Again, I'm sorry for the totally nooby question! Any help at all is much appreciated.

Also, I'm using Chrome, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `canvas` is out of scope. To get it back in scope, either embed the trevor function inside the `start` function, or pass the canvas context as a variable to a closure:

```
function start(){
    var canvastmp = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
    var ctx = canvastmp.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(pos){trevor(ctx,pos)}, false);
}
function trevor(ctx, pos){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    var x = pos.clientX;
    var y = pos.clientY;
    ctx.fillRect(x-25,y-25,100,100);
}
window.addEventListener('load',start,false);
```

Or alternatively, use a more object-like approach:

```
function trevor(ctx) {
    function moveHandler(pos) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
        ctx.fillRect(pos.clientX - 25, pos.clientY - 25, 100, 100);
    }
}
var myTrevor = trevor((document.getElementById('myCanvas')).getContext('2d'));
window.addEventListener('load', myTrevor.moveHandler, false);
```

The nice thing about this is that the contexts are always relevant; trevor only knows the context it's given, and the code that sets up the event handler also retrieves the context.

Answer (score 0):

Your `canvas` variable is defined in the function `start`, but then when you refer to it in the function `trevor` it's out of scope.

Define it out of both functions so it's in scope for both and this works.

See - http://jsfiddle.net/sync/mE4B4/

```
var canvas;

function start() {
    var canvastmp = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    canvas = canvastmp.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', trevor, false);
}

function trevor(pos) {
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
    var x = pos.clientX;
    var y = pos.clientY;
    canvas.fillRect(x - 25, y - 25, 100, 100);
}

window.addEventListener('load', start, false);​
```

Comment: Global variables are an easy way to 'fix' scope issues, but not a good practise. Try a closure instead to pass the context to trevor.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you're using Chrome - if so, please take a look at the built-in inspector (Tools > Developer Tools). The Console tab displays errors. If you take a look there, you'll see something like `Canvas not defined`, which is a useful hint.

The 'canvas' var was out of scope. The following will work:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function mousemove(pos) {
  
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
  
  var x = pos.clientX;
  var y = pos.clientY;

  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(x-25,y-25,50,50);
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove, false);
```

Comment: This will be slower as there is a DOM query (getElementById) inside the loop. The canvas context doesn't change between mouse moves, so why waste time going to get it again?